# Много ли занимают места данные в БД?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

1. Насколько много могут занимать данные в БД?
2. Сжимаются ли записи в таблицах?
3. И стоит ли париться на счёт удаления устаревших записей (если они больше не нужны)?

Comment: Судя по всему в postgresql есть сжатие для больших полей (превышающих размер страницы) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-toast.html

Comment: занимать могут сколько угодно. Надо понимать на сколько они нужны и могут ли неожиданно понадобится. Если в системе присутствуют не поддающиеся оптимизации запросы, выполняющие full scan то удалять конечно надо

Comment: @Mike у меня просто есть данные, которые с течением определённого времени становятся не нужны. Вот и думаю, стоит ли их удалять или просто выводить пользователю сообщение о том, что данные могли устареть.

Comment: лично я предпочитаю ничего не удалять пока оно не ухудшает производительность. вдруг понадобится для разбора полетов или еще чего. а так ответить однозначно невозможно зависит от конкретной ситуации

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Ограничения](https://www.postgresql.org/about/) PostgreSQL:

   - Максимальный размер таблицы: 32 TB
   - Максимальный размер строки: 1.6 TB
   - Максимальный размер поля: 1 GB
2. PostgreSQL использует технику под названием [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/storage-toast.html) для сжатия больших полей.
3. Зависит от конкретного случая. Можно партицировать таблицу по дате, можно как посоветовал Kromster архивировать БД за старые периоды, а в текущей - удалять.

Answer (score 0):

1. Сколько влезет на HDD.
2. (не в курсе)
3. Если кончится место в ОЗУ или хуже того на HDD - переносите старые данные в архивную БД.